# Unclear route "pathMatch" breaking change upgrading to Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-router

One of the Angular upgrade notes at https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=13.0-14.0 about moving to Angular 14 reads "If you are defining routes with pathMatch, you may have to cast it to Route or Routes explicitly. Route.pathMatch is no longer compatible with string type." I may have to cast *what*?

The second sentence contradicts the interface declaration at https://angular.io/api/router/Route, which is:

`pathMatch?: 'prefix' | 'full'`

So, it's still a string type. How do you cast that to Route or Routes?

More specifically, if my existing definition of `routes` begins

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
```

then what is the upgrade note telling me I have to do? Maybe "it" in the note refers to the route, and I need to cast

`{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent }`

to a Route, but what does that have to do with being "no longer compatible with a string type"? I mean, 'full' is a string *and* it matches the type spec `'prefix' | 'full'`, so what's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is turn your current code:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
```

To the following piece of code because of the angular 1 **cast it to Route or Routes explicitly.** :

```
  const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full' as Route['pathMatch'], component: HomeComponent },
```

Don't forget to import the necessary **Route or Routes** imports to make this work, good luck. If tried it and this worked perfectly for me